# Loading JSON Response on Web Application Load (JQuery, Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, django

Well I'm building a Django Web Application which requires to obtained a JSON Response from a given identifier and input within the given tag.

The way which it will work is first it obtained a identifier of the number (surah.id) which will identify which JSON response need to be downloaded (Found between the div):

```
<ul>
    {% for surah in surahs %}
        <li>
            <a href='/quran/{{ surah.id }}/'> {{ surah }} </a>
            <!-- Div Class Below -->
            <div class="d{{ surah.id }}">{{ surah.id }}</div>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No Surah Added</p>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Next it will obtained the JSON data froma given Request:

Example Request: http://quranapi.azurewebsites.net/api/chapter/1

And then it will change the list value based on the Surah Name (in Arabic obtained) So the list will look like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for surah in surahs %}
        <li>
            <a href='/quran/{{ surah.id }}/'> Al Fatiha - The Opening </a>
            <!-- Div Class Below -->
            <div class="d{{ surah.id }}">الفَاتِحَة</div>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No Surah Added</p>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now I attempted using JQuery for this, however I'm stuck on changing the div tags. I can extract the data and get it within a list. However I'm struggling on changing the Div. This is what I attempted:

```
//  _data = []
//  for (i = 0; i < $("li").length; i++) {
//      url = "http://quranapi.azurewebsites.net/api/chapter/" + (i + 1);
//      console.log(url);
//      $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
//          _data.push(_data[i] = result[0].Name)
//          //console.log(_data[i]);
//      });
//  }
```

(Note: I'm new JQuery & Javascript)

So Question is how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really baffled at what you are trying to do with "_data.push(_data[i] = result[0].Name)". This will result in adding the same thing twice. You can see here:  https://jsfiddle.net/6tw1L15f/

Putting that aside and returning back to the main question, what are you trying to "change" about the div? Are you trying to change them from the ids into their names? If so, you need to simply use .text(). Also, I would use a class on your divs to find them. So in total here is what I would do:

```
<ul>
    {% for surah in surahs %}
        <li>
            <a href="/quran/{{ surah.id }}/"> {{ surah }} </a>
            <!-- Div Class Below -->
            <div class="d{{ surah.id }} surah-div"> {{ surah.id }} </div>
        </li>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No Surah Added</p>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And then the Javascript:

```
i = 1;  // You should probably do this index thing differently
$(".surah-div").each(function()
{
    // It is proper to end your urls with slashes
    var url = "http://quranapi.azurewebsites.net/api/chapter/" + i + "/";
    var surah_div = $(this);

    $.getJSON(url, function(result)
    {
        surah_div.text(result[0].Name);
    });

    i++;
}
```

Honestly I wouldn't really do it this way, I am only trying to merge what you have with what I would do. Also there is a SERIOUS flaw with doing this. You need to be VERY careful when putting an ajax inside of a loop. Honestly I have never tried an ajax inside of an "each" like this, but it might suffer from the same problem.

The problem with putting an ajax into a for loop is that you probably use "i" inside of the ajax success function, but by the time the ajax completes, it has already moved on to the next iteration of the for loop and probably many more iterations. Ajax calls are "asynchronous" which means that they don't stop the flow of the code and thus the for loop doesn't wait for it to come back before sending off the next one.

I realize that you aren't using "i" in your case, but that is because you have another flaw that is similar. You are assuming that you will get everything in a particular order (kind of like "i"), but you can't guarantee it.

To protect yourself from all of this nonsense, just make sure that the ajax is put in its own function and call it so that "i" is passed by value and you don't have to worry about it changing in the for loop. Like this:

```
i = 1;  // You should probably do this index thing differently
$(".surah-div").each(function()
{
    // It is proper to end your urls with slashes
    var url = "http://quranapi.azurewebsites.net/api/chapter/" + i + "/";
    var surah_div = $(this);

    fill_in_surah_div(url, surah_div);
    i++;
}

function fill_in_surah_div(url, surah_div)
{
    $.getJSON(url, function(result)
    {
        surah_div.text(result[0].Name);
    });
}
```

### Update:

Answer modified as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much, was stuck all day yesterday. Also thank for the head up with the AJAX section. I did notice when debugging that the 'getJSON' section does get called however it does actually run the loop again, so way you clarified it helps (as I need to do it for the next page again)

Comment: Also one last thing (if anyone else looking at it), I change abit of the code by adding fill_in_surah_div(surah_div) with fill_in_surah_div(url, surah_div) so it can accept the url as well

Comment: Oh indeed, my mistake. I forgot about the url. I will update the answer.